# EMR task keep in RUNNING state even after the Spark job has finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I was running a PySpark job (with Apache Hudi) on AWS EMR on EKS, the driver code was like:

```
with (SparkSession.builder
            .appName(f"App")
            .config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer')
            .config('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension')
            .getOrCreate()) as spark:
    # Add a new column to my Hudi table
    spark.sql('alter table my_table add columns (my_date date)')
    # Merge a data set into my Hudi table
    spark.sql('merge into _mytable ...')
    
    spark.stop()

print('FINISH')
sys.exit(0)
```

This job keeps in `RUNNING` state in EMR, but the job is finished and exited actually. I could see the job was finished in Spark UI. And in the output log, I could see the `FINISH` printed at the last line of my script. Also,  I've checked S3, and the data modification has been finished. But the state of that task in EMR still keep `RUNNING` unless I cancel manually.

Example:
[image: Spark job finished in 2.3 minutes]

Spark History Server shows this job finished in 2.3 minutes. But in AWS EMR Console, it still keep running until I stop it after 50 minutes:

[image: EMR step keep running until I cancel it manually]

Anyone know what causes this problem?